# How to control a unipolar stepper motor (2A/phase) with MOSFETS

Tags: mosfet, control, stepper-motor

I want to control my stepper motor (103H7123-0440) with MOSFETS (IRFB31N20DPBF), however the stepper doesn't turn. I can't understand why it has problem and I would appriciate any help. I have attached the circuit diagram. The MOSFETS are controlled by an NI module (NI9263) which is connected to a cRIO 9045.

[image]

To visualize I have also replaced the stepper motor with some LEDs (each LED represents one coil-diode pair). And this works properly. This confuses me more why the stepper motor doesn't turn.

Comment: Please show scope plots. Be aware that many modern stepper motors should be current controlled, a non-limited DC voltage may exceed the current rating and damage them.

Comment: @Mattman944 Unfortunately, I don't have an oscilloscope to plot graphs.

Comment: An analog output card is a poor choice for this application. What is the voltage from the NI card to the MOSFETs? Since this card can drive negative, you should put a diode from G to S. Also, your voltage divider is reducing your voltage by 2. Change the G-S resistor to 100k.

Comment: Agree with @Mattman944.  Also, I don't think it a good idea to have your motor current running through the NI card.  Try attach power supply "GND" to each source.

Comment: The voltage from the NI module to the MOSFETs is 10V. I will include a diode and change the G-S resistor to 100k. I had also tried to attach source to power supply "GND" but it didn't help.

Comment: Apparently, your motor has a resistance of 1.6 ohms per phase.  With a 24 volt supply, there would be 15 amperes through each phase winding.  The motor is only rated at 2 amperes per phase.  You may have fried the whole thing.  At a minimum, you need some power resistors in series with the winding to limit the current.  Or, reduce the voltage of your power supply.

Comment: That is a good point. But luckily, my power supply can maximal deliver 5A. I guess there is still somewhere an issue. Because if I would have fried anything, it should have heaten up. But everything seems to be fine. And I had also tried to measure the current with a multimeter between a coil and Drain pin. But apparently, no current is flowing.

Comment: Well, what is the voltage output from the NI9263? What is the voltage at the gate?

Comment: I have bought a motor driver now to control my stepper motor. And it works. So, I will leave the circuit with the MOSFETs. But anyway thank you very much. I appreciate your help.